# Migrating complex web app from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, migration

I have a working web app running on .NET 4.7.2, and I need to migrate it to .NET 6.0. I've been facing many problems in changes how .NET Core manages Http libraries and networking.

In particular I'm not able to translate code like the following:

```
protected  bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContext httpContext) 
{
    if (Config.Instance.Test)
         return true;

    var context = httpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context;
    var roles = httpContext.Request?.ServerVariables["HTTP_COMPANY_ROLES"];
    return IsAuthenticate(roles);
}
```

In particular, in the previous snippet, I'm not able to implement how to get `ApplicationInstance` from the `HttpContext` and how to access `ServerVariables` array from current http request, because these properties are not defined (error CS1061) in my current project references and assembly references.

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how solve these issues?

Another question is: in .NET Core there is difference between `HttContext` and `HttContextBase` should I take into account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [HttpContextBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontextbase?view=netframework-4.8.1) in ASP.NET Core. [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is already an abstract class  which is implemented in DefaultHttpContext (see [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs#L16)).

[HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-6.0) don't have the ServerVariables property.  You can use `HttpContext.Request?.Headers` to get these [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iheaderdictionary?view=aspnetcore-6.0#properties).

You can use session to get or set the object used to manage user session data for this request:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("HTTP_COMPANY_ROLES", "aa");

var v1=HttpContext.Session.GetString("HTTP_COMPANY_ROLES");
```

If you use session , note to configure the session for this application or  request by add below code in the Program.cs.

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
app.UseSession();
```

Besides, you can read [Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.